# How to iterate over dictionary using 'enumerate' without assigning loop count to 'key'?

Tags: python, indexing

I have csv file with three headers( A, B and C) , I read this file as dictionary . Where the headers are Keys in the dictionary , and rows are the keys values.

I need to iterate over the dictionary values row by row,  and perform some action then move to the next row(..the first loop output should be as below , without printing the index) :

Expected output in the first loop:

```
A:324087rwer
B:mobile
C:test
```

Current Code:

```
import csv

with open("test.csv") as f:
    rows = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in rows:
         for key, value in enumerate(row.items()):  
            print(key, value)
```

Current Output:

```
0 ('A', '324087rwer')
1 ('B', 'mobile ')
2 ('C', 'take ')
0 ('A', 'fweo8yr30w8yr')
1 ('B', 'keep')
2 ('C', 'remove')
0 ('A', 'erwes')
1 ('B', 'website')
2 ('C', 'blacklist')
```

Note : I don't want the index to be printed .

Many thanks

Comment: Try: `for key, value in row.items()`: - there should be no index now

Answer (score 1):

The `enumerate` function is returning an iterator containing the loop count  plus another tuple containing the dictionary key, value pairs.

This could be described with a type hint such as:

```
Tuple[int, Tuple[KT, VT]]
```

Hence, in the inner `for-loop`, the `key` variable is being assigned to the loop count and the `value` variable is being assigned the tuple (`Tuple[KT, VT]`).

If you do not need the loop counter, then you could write:

```
import csv

with open("test.csv") as f:
    rows = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in rows:
         for key, value in row.items():  
            print(key, value)
```

If you need the loop counter, then the following would work:

```
import csv

with open("test.csv") as f:
    rows = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in rows:
        for count, (key, value) in enumerate(rows.items()):  
            print(key, value)
```